# php shell_exec return value to javascript variable not working

Tags: javascript, php

I want to  get the output string from php_exec function to a javascript variable. But it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$val1 = "val1 ok";
$val2 = shell_exec('ls');
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.write("<?php echo $val2 ?>"); // val1 works but not val2
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see val1 get printed but not val2. why ?

Comment: just after `$val2 = shell_exec('ls');`, put `var_dump($val2);` to debug.

Comment: you'd better use var_export() instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php),

> The output from the executed command or **NULL** if an error occurred or
>   the command produces no output.

and the `shell_exec` function "is disabled when PHP is running in [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)."

`$val2` is not displayed because its value is `null`.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$val1 = "val1 ok";
$val2 = shell_exec('ls');
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.write("<?php echo 'val2 is '.$val2 ?>"); // val1 works but not val2
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

`val2 is`

Comment: Thanks Hemal, But if i put "echo $val2;" inside the php code, it shows the correct output. So val2 is not null.

Comment: Plz send me output which is display in php. In my server `safe_mode` is Off, So i get null value in php output.

Comment: It says "a.php"(only file in that directory). There is another problem, I dont see "val2 is" part as result from your edited code. It is completely empty. When $val2 is involved everything become empty.

Comment: Please do not use slang abbreviations of English words such as "*b'cos*" instead of "*because*", not everyone would be able to tell what you're trying to say if you're not using proper English.

Comment: shell_exec('ls') will return an array, you should implode the out put to a string before passing it to JavaScript. $val2 = implode(shell_exec('ls'));